# Using SolrNet for Spatial Search and multiple Columns

Tags: solr, full-text-search, spatial, solrnet

I am new to Solr. Using following Solrnet query to run my search.

```
results = solr.Query(new LocalParams { { "type", "dismax" }, { "qf", "Title Description" } } + new SolrQuery(Keywords) , queryOptions);
```

The above query works without any issues. I tried spatial search in the same query using following.

```
results = solr.Query(new LocalParams { { "type", "dismax" },{ "pt", "40.7143528,-74.0059731" },{ "sfield", "coords" },{ "d", "15" }, { "qf", "Title Description" } } + new SolrQuery(Keywords) , queryOptions);
```

Above query doesn't take spatial search into account, it rather return results from all documents.

The same query does a spatial search if change the "type" to "geofilt".

```
results = solr.Query(new LocalParams { { "type", "geofilt" },{ "pt", "40.7143528,-74.0059731" },{ "sfield", "coords" },{ "d", "15" }, { "qf", "Title Description" } } + new SolrQuery(Keywords) , queryOptions);
```

But this time, it doesn't return the relevant results. i.e. if user searched for "Toyota", above query with type=geofilt might return "FORD" within 15 kms.

Can you please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: please format the code snippets properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two clauses here: the dismax query by keywords, and the geospatial query, but you're trying to cram both into a single clause. Instead, represent them as separate query clauses (separate query objects).

Pseudocode:

```
var spatial = new LocalParams {{"type","geofilt"},...} + new SolrQuery("");
queryOptions.FilterQueries = new[] {spatial};
var keyword = new LocalParams { { "type", "dismax" }, { "qf", "Title Description" } } + new SolrQuery(Keywords);
var results = solr.Query(keyword, queryoptions);
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I would have to run nested queries using Solrnet? I am really new to this stuff, would it be possible to get a couple of lines pseudo code (for Solrnet) so that I could understand and do more research on it.

Comment: This resulted in a compile time error.i.e. Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SolrNet.ISolrQuery' and 'SolrNet.ISolrQuery'   

`var spatial = new LocalParams { { "type", "geofilt" }, { "pt", "40.7143528,-74.0059731" }, { "sfield", "coords" }, { "d", "15" }} + new SolrQuery("");  
                
var keywords = new LocalParams { { "type", "dismax" }, { "qf", "Title Description" } } + new SolrQuery(SearchKeywords);  
                var results = solr.Query(spatial && keywords, queryoptions);  `

Comment: Sorry i am trying to format code snippet but doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @Peter: I'm not even sure Solr supports multiple LocalParams in the `q` parameter. Let me know if it works. If not, you'll have to move one of the queries to filter queries.

Comment: It did not work. I was trying to hack & edit the Solr query from logs to get it working.

It works like this

`http://localhost:8080/tempsolr/select/?q={!type=dismax qf='Title Description'}honda&fq={!geofilt}PubDate:[2011-06-29T01:16:59Z TO 2011-07-29T01:17:00Z]&rows=10&sfield=LatLon&pt=40.7143528,-74.0059731&d=50`

Now I am adding, `sfield , pt, d` as ExtraParameters. The only problem I am facing is with the 'geofilt'. I try to add it as a filter and it comes in query as `fq=type:geofilt`. I need to get it like this `fq={!geofilt}`

Help please?